# xpath to increment the rows

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Does anyone know how to create a counter within the xpath to increment the rows?

```
cli=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/a')
```

example: html/body/div[2] next html/body/div[3]. etc

Answer (score 0):

Just concantenate the string. or use format. 2 is starting it ends before 4. so 2 and 3.

```
for i in range(2,4):
    cli=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div["+str(i)+"]")
```

You could instead do

```
clis=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body//div')
```

which retrieves all the elements and then do the below to loop through each of it's div webelement.

```
for cli in clis:
```

clis[2:] would make it second div after as well.

Comment: Interesting.  Is that what the double bracket's adds? as opposed to a single `/` prior to the div?

Comment: Pretty much find all the divs after that element.

Comment: If this answer helps please checkmark it as correct.